# Magento quick search issue

Tags: magento, search

I have an issue with Magento quick search. If I do a search for a product, e.g. m-400, the result page displays this product as well as other products that contain the term m-400. The issue is the the main product, which has m-400 in the title is not displayed first (try it for yourself at (http://marsden.webresponsive.co.uk/index.php/). I changed the sort order by name, then sku, cleared the cached, reindexed everything at every change, followed these instructions (http://optimiseblog.co.uk/magento-catalog-search-broken-not-working/), but no luck.
Does anyone have a solution or a list of settings that I need to check?

Answer (score 0):

The magento built in search is not all that good in all honesty. What I do, is replace it with something much more powerful and more configurable to suite the needs such as the one you have highlighted. [Sphinx search](http://sphinxsearch.com/) is an open source search program and their are plugins available to integrate magento with it. [Aheadworks](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/advanced-search.html) provides the one I use (It does cost though), and this is allows you to configure product field weightings through the admin. e.g. SKU match = 100, Title = 75, Description = 50 etc.

There is a guide [here](http://tonyhb.com/using-sphinx-within-magento-plus-optimising-search-result-rankings-weights-and-relevancy) for making your own sphinx config file and integrating magento with sphinx which may be of use if you didn't want to purchase a module.